# libGDX: Moving camera in Stage Viewport

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx, viewport

I developed a libGDX application on Android that uses a Stage with Viewport and Camera.
I wanted to change the viewport's camera position, but nothing happens. I didn't know what can cause this problem.

If I change
`stage.getViewport().getCamera().position.x`
or I call
`stage.getViewport().getCamera().translate()`

 anywhere, the camera position doesn't change.

I call `stage.getViewport().getCamera().update()` after these methods but nothing happens.

Comment: You need to add a question in there. The description is good, but what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I are right, I change it, just a sec.

Comment: What do you think now, you can edit it if you want to.

Comment: much better. No question mark to be found, but you made it clear what expected result you are not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was that, when I updated my Viewport in my ApplicationListener's resize function:

```
@Override
    public void resize(final int width, final int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
    }
```

I set the third parameter to `true` and this way the camera is recentered all the time, and my calls were ineffective. To solve the problem set it to `false`, or remove it simply because that function has a 2 paramtered signature as well.

I share this problem because it was difficult for me to find out what's going on, and this might spare some time for others in the same situation.